# How to sort table using two fields?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**UPDATED**

sample JSON:

```
[{  'student': 'A',
    'std': [ { 'cls': 3, 'date': '26/12/2022', 'flag': true },          
             { 'cls': 2, 'date': '16/11/2021'  'flag': true },
             { 'cls': 1, 'date': '25/11/2020', 'flag': false }]
  },
  { 'student': 'B',
    'std': [ {'cls': 3, 'date': '26/12/2022', 'flag': false},
             {'cls': 2, 'date': '16/11/2021', 'flag': true },
             {'cls': 1, 'date': '25/11/2020', 'flag': false}]
  }]
```

I have create table using above kind of JSON, as below:

```
 <tbody>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let s of student">
     <tr *ngFor="let std of s.std" class="card-text">
       <td>               {{s.student}} </td>
       <td class="event"> {{std.cls}}   </td>
       <td class="venue"> {{std.date}}  </td>
       <td class="venue"> {{std.flag}}  </td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

my question is how can I **sort the table using date column (from recent to old) also with flags (true on top false on bottom)** in Angular.

Desire Output:

```
student  cls        date flag
A          3 26/12/2022  true
A          2 16/11/2021  true
B          2 16/11/2021  true
B          3 26/12/2022  false
A          1 25/11/2020  false 
B          1 25/11/2020  false
```

Comment: What's your *expected* output?

Answer (score 0):

Let's set it as a variable:

```js
let data = [{'student': 'A', 'std':[{'cls':3, 'date':'26/12/2022'}....
```

Now you can do a sort function like so (Generic example):

```js
data.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

For your case, I guess you want to sort by `std`, so it will look like this:

```js
data.sort(function(a,b){
  // Find the earliest date in the array std for b and a
  const aDate = a.std.sort((a1,b1)=>{
    return new Date(a1.date) - new Date(b1.date)
  })[0]
  const bDate = a.std.sort((a1,b1)=>{
    return new Date(a1.date) - new Date(b1.date)
  })[0] 
  return new Date(bDate.date) - new Date(aDate.date);
});
```

Comment: Hi @denislexic Thank you for your reply I am looking for date sorting, sorry I am new to angualar can I ask How can I use data.sort() in HTML while tableing?

Comment: `data.sort` is just plain javascript, independent of Angular. Because your dates are nested within another array, I don't think you can use standard `angular` sorting method. I could try to explain `sort` but They probably do a better job here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: your code not bring the desire output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

- try use ng-repeat and pileline to create order date in table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy: sortByDate"> // ASC order
  <td>{{ student.student }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.std.cls }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.std.date }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi if I am writing table following way, its not identifying the student in TD. please check my updated question code.

Comment: **never**, **never** use a pipe to sort a table.

Comment: @Eliseo please explain, why not?

Comment: "Angular doesn’t offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Earlier in this page, you learned that such pipes must be impure and that Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.

Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second."

Comment: The solution is sort the array in a functión, not using a pipe

Comment: Hi @Eliseo could you please help to get my desire output?

Comment: your code not bring the desire output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Sort an array is create a function that get two elements of the array and return 1 if a>b, -1 if b<a and 0 if a==b. This usually create a function (using flaw arrow) and conditional operator

```
dataSorted=data.sort((a:any,b:any)=>a>b?1:
                                    a<b?-1:
                                    0)
```

When we have an array of object we compare the "key"

```
dataSorted=data.sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.key>b.key?1:
                                    a.key<b.key?-1:
                                    0)
```

If we have two keys, key1 and key2 (first we want to order by key1 and if they are equals by key2) we makes in two steps

```
dataSorted=data.sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
     if (a.key1==b.key1)
     {
       return a.key2>b.key2?1:
              a.key2<b.key2?-1:
              0
     }
     else
     {
        return a.key1>b.key1?1:
            a.key1<b.key1?-1:
            0
     }
     })
```

Really it's uneccessary the else so we can do

```
dataSorted=data.sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
     if (a.key1==b.key1)
       return a.key2>b.key2?1:
              a.key2<b.key2?-1:
              0

     return a.key1>b.key1?1:
            a.key1<b.key1?-1:
            0
     })
```

But there're a problem when we have the dates in not standard way: yyyy-MM-dd because it's dificult sort or convert to Date. So the first is add a new property `normalizeDate` taht convert in yyy-MM-dd

```
  this.data.forEach(x=>{
    //first add the new property "normalizeDate"
    x.std.forEach((c:any)=>{
      c.normalizeDate=c.date.split('/').reverse().join('-')
    })
    //after sort by two keys
  
    x.std.sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
       if (a.flag==b.flag)
         return a.normalizeDate>b.normalizeDate?1:
                a.normalizeDate<b.normalizeDate?-1:
                0
  
       return a.flag>b.flag?-1:  //see that I interchange the 1 and -1
              a.flag<b.flag?1:   //that's because false<true
              0
       })
  })
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1prvng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: your code not bring the desire output as requested.

Comment: @user20042770, thanks for the advise, the dates are orderered from old to recent, it's only interchange the `1` and `-1` in the normalize Date comparision